# Ubuntu 12.04 Booting Issues

Tags: boot

I am almost on the verge of tears :(
Though not a techie, did contribute towards translating ubuntu help ...once upon a time, when i had the free time

have been a great fan and propagator of Ubuntu for the last 8 years !

presently running/using Ubuntu 12.04
today i accepted the automatic updates
however, instead of restarting the computer i just used the normal shutdown as i was running short of time

back from office - i start the computer only to get the 'grub' prompt

i am at a total loss of what to do and backup/restore my files
booted thru the 'live' disk
...but still unable to access files from the computer HDD as it says
that i do not have permissions to read those files :(

PLEASE PLEASE HELP ME
else after this catastrophe i am at a total loss , as to which OS to trust !!!

Thanks & Regards
Sumit D Garg
India

Answer (score 0):

I am not a pro but can help.

Ubuntu have two sections. 
One is of FileSystem which can be accessed by a admin.
Second is FileSystem/Home//

In this second you will be able to access Documents/Downloads/Music/Pictures/Videos which have permissions to be access by all. Unless you have changed the permissions.

So with help of LiveDVD or Bootable USB, you should be able access those files.
Copy to external drive and get all your data back.

Another way to copy directories or files is via terminal.
cp

Answer (score -1):

1). First you obtain a live cd .

2). Then load with that os.

3). Open the "Terminal" .

4). Install boot loader in the primary disk that contain your lost partitions.

5). Then use the command  "update-grub"  to fetch all the partitions details . (Before that make sure you mount all the partitions )

Comment: Please improve your answer by providing more detail.